# It is easy/likely for children to be addicted to video games

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following is more commonly heard?

> It is **easy** for children to be addicted to video games.
>
> It is **likely** for children to be addicted to video games.
>
> It is **easy** for accidents to happen during a speedy car ride.
>
> It is **likely** for accidents to happen during a speedy car ride.

(These are stand-alone sentences, with no other context. )

A teacher, who is not a native speaker of English, cautioned against using **easy** in these two contexts because they are not disucssing the difficulty of performing a task, but the likelihood of an event happening.

However, I feel that **easy** is not only valid, but might even be more common in these two sentences. I feel that a sentence in a Longman dictionary uses **easy** in the same way:  It would have been easy for the team to lose the game.

Comment: Either word sounds wrong with "...for children to **be** addicted", because *to be* describes a state.  The sentence would be more fluent with "... **become** addicted."

Comment: **Easy** doesn't have to describe things you are trying to do. It can refer to accidents that can readily happen if a person is not taking care.

Comment: The construction: **It is likely for.....** is a most unlikely way to start sentences such as those above. The idiomatic construction would be: **Accidents are likely to happen / Children are likely to become.** This is not true, however, for sentences starting: **It is easy....** You might well hear:: **It is easy for someone to get through your window.""

Comment: @RonaldSole This is very interesting. I googled and found another teacher caution against **It is likely for** in this webpage. https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/is-it-is-likely-for-sb-to-do-sth-correct.184009/       However, I also found https://ludwig.guru/s/it+is+likely+for with sentences like "it is likely for abuses of power to occur." from The Guardian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, **easy** is an appropriate choice of words, as is **likely**. They are interchangeable in this context.

Your sentences, however, are a little awkward in American English. I would rewrite the first two as:

> It is easy for children to **become** addicted to video games.

> It is likely **that** children **will become** addicted to video games.

There are other variations possible, for example, you can say "might become" instead of "will become."

In the second two sentences, if there is an accident, it's not the car ride that causes it, it's the excessive speed of the car that causes the accident. So you wouldn't make the car ride the subject of the second part of the sentence (and you wouldn't describe a car ride as "speedy"). You would probably say:

> It's **easy** for accidents to happen or It's **likely** for accidents to happen:
>
> - when you're going fast
> - when you're driving fast
> - when the car is going fast